# A Tree of QGraphicsItem?

Tags: qt

I was wondering if it would be possible to create a QGraphicsItem in a QGraphicsScene that behaves like a QTreeWidget. This QGraphicsItem should be a tree of QGraphicsItems in the scene, with all the capabilities of a QTreeWidget: Where you can expand, collapse and change the order of the items in the stack, while keeping track of the indices with drag and drop capabilities.

Would this be possible by inheriting from QGraphicsItem and QTreeWidget/QAbstractItemView?
Maybe this has been done before or QT already have this functionality(I haven't seen anything like this in the documentation. I know that a QGraphicsItem can have children, that could be a starting point.

Comment: It might be possible to implement the functionality you want via your own code, but it would be a lot of work.  Inheriting from `QGraphicsItem` and `QTreeWidget` won't work, since a `QTreeWidget` doesn't know how to handle `QGraphicsItems`.  You could use a `QGraphicsProxyWidget` object to place a `QTreeWidget` into your `QGraphicsScene`, but the embedded `QTreeWidget` would still handle/display only `QTreeWidgetItems`, not `QGraphicsItems`.

Comment: I tried the ```QGraphicsProxyWidget``` approach but for me it was impossible to allow the items in the ```QTreeWidget``` to interact with the scene(The items are other widgets). For Example: I wanted to get the ```rect center``` of a widget inside a widget in a tree element and I could not find a way.

Comment: Maybe inheriting from QAbstractItemModel?

Comment: You'd need to take the source code for QTreeWidget and re-write it to use the QGraphicsScene/QGraphicsItem API instead of the APIs it currently uses.  Good luck with that :/

Comment: The following link is combining the QGraphicsItem with QAbstractItemModel. I think this is what I was looking for(Although I'm quite new to programming and don't know how to implement it yet. Any thoughts? 

Article: https://invalidmagic.wordpress.com/2010/10/05/qgraphicsscene-used-as-a-qabstractitemview-iii/